# Oracle/SQL Query issue

Tags: oracle, join

I am sort of a newbie to oracle/sql. I am trying to pull from the same column different values and add them with some other information. The other information is not the issue it is trying to count and add here the problem comes in. 
I am connecting to an oracle database. Here is what i have

```
SELECT
EV.PUBLIC_DESCRIPTION,
EV.EVENT_DATE,
ES.PRICE,
BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE,
PCA.ADDR1,
PCA.ADDR2,
PCA.CITY,
PCA.POSTAL_CODE,
PCE.EMAIL,
PC.FORMATTED_NAME,
PCP.PHONE_NUMBER,
PCP.SECONDARY,
SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRADLT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRADTE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRSTND' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GSTDTE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GROUDI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS "Adults",
SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRCHILD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRCHTE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Paid Child',
SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRPCH' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Free Child',
SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRCOMP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Comps'
FROM EVENT EV
INNER JOIN EVENT_SEAT ES ON EV.EVENT_ID = ES.EVENT_ID
INNER JOIN BUYER_TYPE BT ON ES.BUYER_TYPE_ID = BT.BUYER_TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN PATRON_ORDER PO ON ES.ORDER_ID = PO.ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN PATRON_ACCOUNT PA ON ES.ATTENDING_PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID = PA.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID
INNER JOIN PATRON_CONTACT PC ON PA.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID = PC.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID
INNER JOIN PATRON_CONTACT_ADDRESS PCA ON PC.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID = PCA.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID
INNER JOIN PATRON_CONTACT_EMAIL PCE ON PCA.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID = PCE.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID
INNER JOIN PATRON_CONTACT_PHONE PCP ON PCE.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID = PCP.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID
GROUP BY EV.PUBLIC_DESCRIPTION, EV.EVENT_DATE
ORDER BY ES.TRANSACTION_ID DESC, PCP.SECONDARY DESC, PCP.PHONE_NUMBER DESC, PC.FORMATTED_NAME DESC, PCE.EMAIL DESC, PCA.POSTAL_CODE DESC, PCA.CITY DESC, PCA.ADDR2 DESC, PCA.ADDR1 DESC, BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE DESC, ES.PRICE DESC;
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You seem to have forgotten a very important part of your post, the part that explains what the issue is.

Comment: why did you tag `sql server`, as per you this is purely `Oracle`- they are different products.

Comment: my apologies, i just clicked the tags not thinking,

Comment: the error i get is fFROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: There's only one `FROM` in your code. Have a look around. I think perhaps Oracle prefers `"` over `'` for column name delimiters i.e. `AS "Comps"`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid is correct - the problem is that you are using `'` for column aliases, which is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decide which technique you want to use, currently you are using 2 techniques and they are colliding.

For this you must know: COUNT() will increment by one for every NON-NULL value

So, to use COUNT() with a case expression do this

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRSTND' THEN 1 END)
or
COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRSTND' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

OR, don't use COUNT(), use SUM() instead

```
SUM(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRSTND' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

To add conditions together, I suggest you use the case expression better
Instead of something like this:

```
 , COUNT(CASE  WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRADLT' THEN 1 END) 
 + COUNT(CASE  WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRADTE' THEN 1 END) 
 + COUNT(CASE  WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRSTND' THEN 1 END) 
 + COUNT(CASE  WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GSTDTE' THEN 1 END) 
 + COUNT(CASE  WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GROUDI' THEN 1 END) AS "Adults"
```

Use this:

```
 COUNT(CASE  WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE IN ('GRADLT','GRADTE','GRSTND','GSTDTE','GROUDI') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

There is also an issue with your GROUP BY, which MUST contain ALL non-aggregating columns. I think your query should look more like this:

```
SELECT
      EV.PUBLIC_DESCRIPTION
    , EV.EVENT_DATE
    , ES.PRICE
 /*  , BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE */
    , PCA.ADDR1
    , PCA.ADDR2
    , PCA.CITY
    , PCA.POSTAL_CODE
    , PCE.EMAIL
    , PC.FORMATTED_NAME
    , PCP.PHONE_NUMBER
    , PCP.SECONDARY
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE IN ('GRADLT', 'GRADTE', 'GRSTND', 'GSTDTE', 'GROUDI') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Adults"
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE IN ('GRCHILD', 'GRCHTE', 'GRPCH', 'GRCOMP') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Free Child"
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE = 'GRCOMP' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Comps"
FROM EVENT EV
INNER JOIN EVENT_SEAT ES
      ON EV.EVENT_ID = ES.EVENT_ID
INNER JOIN BUYER_TYPE BT
      ON ES.BUYER_TYPE_ID = BT.BUYER_TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN PATRON_ORDER PO
      ON ES.ORDER_ID = PO.ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN PATRON_ACCOUNT PA
      ON ES.ATTENDING_PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID = PA.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID
INNER JOIN PATRON_CONTACT PC
      ON PA.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID = PC.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID
INNER JOIN PATRON_CONTACT_ADDRESS PCA
      ON PC.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID = PCA.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID
INNER JOIN PATRON_CONTACT_EMAIL PCE
      ON PCA.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID = PCE.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID
INNER JOIN PATRON_CONTACT_PHONE PCP
      ON PCE.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID = PCP.PATRON_ACCOUNT_ID
GROUP BY
      EV.PUBLIC_DESCRIPTION
    , EV.EVENT_DATE
    , ES.PRICE
  /*  , BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE */
    , PCA.ADDR1
    , PCA.ADDR2
    , PCA.CITY
    , PCA.POSTAL_CODE
    , PCE.EMAIL
    , PC.FORMATTED_NAME
    , PCP.PHONE_NUMBER
    , PCP.SECONDARY
/* check all these columns exist in the select clause
ORDER BY
      ES.TRANSACTION_ID DESC
    , PCP.SECONDARY DESC
    , PCP.PHONE_NUMBER DESC
    , PC.FORMATTED_NAME DESC
    , PCE.EMAIL DESC
    , PCA.POSTAL_CODE DESC
    , PCA.CITY DESC
    , PCA.ADDR2 DESC
    , PCA.ADDR1 DESC
    , BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE DESC
    , ES.PRICE DESC
*/
```

When you come the the final clause: **ORDER BY** you can ONLY reference columns that exist in the select clause. This example would FAIL

```
select column1 from table1 group by column1 order by fred
```

but this would work:

```
select column1 from table1 group by column1 order by column1
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down and explaining it to me! i made the adjustments you suggested which make the query look A LOT cleaner. i get an error now that says not a group by express. Do i need to add this section to the GROUp BY?

Comment: I now notice you have the column BT.BUYER_TYPE_CODE in the select list and I copied it into the group by too. You probably need to remove that column in both locations (and order by). All columns in the order by clause must exist in the select list, check that.

Comment: i appreciate you taking the time to help with this. I tried the whole query as you rewrote it but i get the error ORA-00979, not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: I am doing what I can... please ensure you refresh the answer ... take the time to read my comments and changes. I cannot test it and I must get to bed soon.

Comment: the problem is your ORDER BY clause, it references columns that are not in the select list

Comment: Used_By_Already, Thank you so much for your help and explanations the query works great now! Thank You So Much!

Comment: Thank you. You can also show appreciation by ticking the answer that solves your question, and by upvoting any answers that assisted as well. It is impolite to not do this by the way (many site newbies seem to ignore that). When you have time look through the site for tips on how to ask better question, that way you get less downvotes on the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your column aliases `'Paid Child'`, `'Free Child'`, `'Comps'` should not be wrapped in single quotes.  You should be using double quotes like you are already for `"Adults"`.

So they should instead be:

- `"Paid Child"`
- `"Free Child"`
- `"Comps"`

Or better yet, consider naming your aliases without any spaces, so you don't have to worry about wrapping the aliases in anything, like this:

- `paid_child`
- `free_child`
- `comps`

---

[Documentation on Database Object Names and Qualifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223):

> **Database Object Naming Rules**
>
> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent the name of an object with a **quoted identifier** or a **nonquoted identifier**.
>
> - A quoted identifier begins and ends with ***double quotation marks (")***. If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.
> - A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.
>
> ...
>
> Although ***column aliases***, table aliases, usernames, and passwords are not objects or parts of objects, they ***must also follow these naming rules*** unless otherwise specified in the rules themselves.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i made the adjustments you suggested. Now i get the error not a single-group group function

Comment: You would need to include all the non-aggregated columns that are in your select column list into the group by.